# How to reuse Activity content in another one?

Tags: android, android-activity, code-reuse

I haven't found a way to have it so an activity exists and the activity would load into another activity.

The reason I want to do this is I am attempting to have it so an activity can be loaded from an external file(if this is possible).

Is there a way to do this? Sorry if I have no code to display since I have no idea how this would be possible(if it is).

EDIT: Am I asking the wrong question? I didn't know how else to ask the question because I have looked online for a solution, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Seems your design is unclear. You need to restudy about android. I think you can go by Fragments if u dont know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to reuse User Interface sections, you should use the [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).
They are similar to the User Controls available in many .Net technologies (WPF, Asp.Net, ecc) if know them.

Be aware, it takes some time to understand how they works.